# Laravel eloquent query builder - Sum with group on relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I am looking for a query builder solution for the following:

Table: transaction_types

```
| id | type_hash | description     | category |
|----|-----------|-----------------|----------|
| 1  | abcd      | sale price      | sale     |
| 2  | dbac      | sale tax        | sale     |
| 3  | agft      | sale shipping   | sale     |
| 4  | pgsk      | refund price    | refund   |
| 5  | sa2r      | refund tax      | refund   |
| 6  | sdf4      | refund shipping | refund   |
```

Table: transactions

```
| id | type_hash | amount |
|----|-----------|--------|
| 1  | abcd      | 12     |
| 2  | dbac      | 14     |
| 3  | agft      | 19     |
| 4  | pgsk      | -20    |
| 5  | sa2r      | -12    |
| 6  | sdf4      | -7     |
```

Relationship - transaction belongs to transaction type

```
public function transactionType() : BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(TransactionType::class, 'type_hash', 'type_hash');
}
```

The result I am looking for on the transactions table is:

- Amount aggregated `sum(amount) as amount`
- Group transactions by `TransactionType.category`

i.e.

```
| Results | transactionType.category | sum(amount)   |
|---------|--------------------------|---------------|
| 1       | sale                     | 45            |
| 2       | refund                   | -39           |
```

I can get the following working, but ideally I want to do all the aggregation in the query builder, not in the collection:

```
Transaction::selectRaw('sum(amount) as amount')
    ->with('transactionType')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('transactionType.category');
```

I have tried the following (and variations of), but cannot get it working:

```
Transaction::selectRaw('sum(amount) as amount')
    ->with(['transactionType' => function($query){
        $query->select('category')->groupBy('category');
    }])
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the generated SQL, you need to select the column you group by, and you need to call the get() after the `groupBy` or else you'd be calling the `groupBy` on the collection, not the query builder object.  So you should be able to do:

```
Transaction::selectRaw('transactionType.category, sum(amount) as amount')
->with('transactionType')
->groupBy('transactionType.category')
->get();
```

Or Less Eloquent

```
DB::table('transaction')
->join(
    'transaction_type',
    'transaction_type.id',
    '=',
    'transaction.transaction_type_id'
)->selectRaw('transationType.category, sum(amount)')
->groupBy('transactionTyle.category')
->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can get the join to work when using table names, but I really want to get eloquent version. My SQL error is `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'transactionType.category' in 'field list' (SQL: select sum(amount) as amount, transactionType.category from `transactions` group by `transactionType`.`category`)`. Any ideas?

Comment: The second query also works with your model: `Transaction::join(...)`. Is that what you mean by "Eloquent version"?