# How would you aggregate a column in one model grouped by a column in another model in Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I know this is simple, but I just cant get past this problem in an **Eloquent way**.
For a simple scenario where a product master and transaction table are maintained thus:

```
**Table : Products**

prod_id
Prod Name
Manufacturer

**Table : Sales**

prod_id
qty_sold
selling_price
```

A relationship is already established on "product" model

```
public function sales()

{
return $this->hasMany('\App\Models\Sale','prod_id','prod_id');
}
```

How do I run an eloquent query on Product to return the sales quantity (sum('qty')) grouped by manufacturer?

Secondly, is it possible to run a query on Sale model to get aggregates grouped by Manufacturer (from Product Model)?

Basically, I want the aggregates from one model to group by a column in another related model.

Here's a possible SQL query (excuse typos, I'm on a mobile device) :

```
SELECT products.manufacturer, sum(qty_sold) 
FROM products LEFT JOIN sales on products.prod_id = sales.prod_id 
GROUP BY products.manufacturer
```

Comment: It will be better if you show us sample data and expected results. You said that this is simple but you just don't know how to make this with Eloquent - so I assume that you know how to make this with raw sql query? If that's true - show this query :)  This way it will be easier to understand and help.

Comment: Raw query added

Comment: I think it is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55834846/laravel-eloquent-query-builder-sum-with-group-on-relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it with something like this using a `DB::raw()` select:

```php
DB::table('products')
->leftJoin('sales', 'products.prod_id', '=', 'sales.prod_id')
->select(DB::raw('products.manufacturer, SUM(qty_sold)'))
->groupBy('products.manufacturer')
->get()
```

You could also try something like:

```
$sales = Product::select(DB::raw('products.manufacturer, SUM(qty_sold)'))
                  ->groupBy('products.manufacturer')
                  ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any alternative to this, where I don't have to use the table names and instead use the existing Models and relationships?

Comment: This works, but then can i do a groupby() ?
I need the sum by manufacturer : something like following ?
$sales = Product::withSum('sales', 'qty_sold')->groupby('manufacturer')->get()

Comment: Thanks Andrew. It helps. But I still need to use DB::raw (and the table names) which does not use the defined models, which troubles me. But I am marking this as accepted for now, as i am not sure if this is even possible .